# What does the nVIDIA CUDA driver do exactly?

Tags: cuda, driver, nvidia

What does Nvidia CUDA driver do exactly? from the perspective of using CUDA.
The driver passes the kernel code, with the execution configuration (#threads, #blocks)...
and what else?

I saw some post that the driver should be aware of the number of available SMs.
But isn't that unnecessary ? Once the kernel is passed to GPU, the GPU scheduler just needs to spread the work to available SMs...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The GPU isn't a fully autonomous device, it requires a *lot* of help from the host driver to do even
the simplest things. As I understand it the driver contains at least:

- JIT compiler/optimizer (PTX assembly code can be compiled by the driver at runtime, the driver will also recompile code to match the execution architecture of the device if required and possible)
- Device memory management
- Host memory management (DMA transfer buffers, pinned and mapped host memory, unified addressing model)
- Context and runtime support (so code/heap/stack/printf buffer memory management), dynamic symbol management, streams, etc
- Kernel "grid level" scheduler (includes managing multiple simultaneous kernels on architectures that support it)
- Compute mode management
- Display driver interop (for DirectX and OpenGL resource sharing)

That probably represents the bare minimum that is required to get some userland device code onto a GPU and running via the host side APIs.

Comment: Just one more question if you don't mind. That "Unified addressing model" is somewhat like a virtual memory, right ? That virtual memory addresses used in the CUDA kernel will get translated to actual physical GPU memory addresses (global, local, shared, ...). Is this purely done at the driver level ? I think that the driver just needs to translate the unified address to actual physical address (global, local, ...) while GPU HW does not need to know anything about this virtual stuff. Am I understanding correctly ? Thanks !

Comment: What I meant by unified addressing is the scheme in CUDA 4.0 and later which lets multiple GPUs and certain other devices like network interfaces map themselves into a common address space with the host. This is all done by the driver. Fermi cards seem to have a TLB for doing the internal mapping of virtual addresses to hardware features. That needs to be programmed, which is where the driver will come in, but otherwise address translation should be done by the device.